# Ubuntu randomly freezes. 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Before this is marked as a duplicate, I already checked the answers to the other questions and they either don't work for me or are outdated. Anyways, Hello I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and it likes to randomly freeze on me. I cannot open a TTY or even move the mouse... Should I reinstall or...

Comment: Try lowering your swappiness value.

Comment: Very little to no swap is being used.

Comment: Oh... there's two of you... giggle. @NerdOfLinux don't start changing vm.swappiness until you've asked some basic questions first... like... how much RAM how much swap? Have you fsck'd the hard disk? Does this only happen with a certain application running? What kind of processors? Make/model #? Give us more details if you expect a reasonable answer.

Comment: Do you have Intel Bay Trail processors?